# Adding event listeners with Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm having trouble adding eventListener to through javascript. Ok, I have a function that creates 4 anchor elements. I want to add an event to them onmouseover that calls a function to change their backkground color. Here's the code (look at the next to last line of createAnchor() to find the relevant code line.

```
function createAanchor(index) { 
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            var text = getText(index);
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            var t = document.createTextNode(text);
            a.href = getHref(index);
            a.appendChild(t);
            a.style.textAlign = "center";
            a.style.fontSize = "1.2em";
            a.style.color = "white";
            a.style.fontFamily = "arial";
            a.style.fontWeight = "bold";
            a.style.textDecoration = "none";
            a.style.lineHeight = "238px";
            a.style.width = "238px";
            a.style.margin = "5px";
            a.style.background = eightColors(index);
            a.style.position = "absolute";
            a.addEventListener("onmouseover", changeColor());
            return a;
    }

    function changeColor() {
        alert("EVENT WORKING");
    }
```

Ok here's the problem. When the function gets to `a.addEventListener("onmouseover", changeColor());` the `function changeColors()` executes, but it does not execute later on `onmouseover` Why is this?

Comment: P.S. I also tried `a.onmouseover = changeColor();` it gives the same result as `a.addEventListener("onmouseover", changeColor());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is no such event `onmouseover`, the event is called `mouseover`.
2. You have to pass a function reference to `addEventlistener`. `()` calls the function, as you already noticed, so... don't call it.

This is how it should be:

```
a.addEventListener("mouseover", changeColor);
```

I recommend to read [the excellent articles about event handling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) on quirksmode.org.

Comment: Thank you for an informative answer. Though I have 2 questions. 1. What is the difference between `mouseover`and `onmouseover`? 2. Is the function reference you mentioned just the name of the function but without the parentheses for parameters?

Comment: 1: The event name is always without `on`. DOM elements and HTML elements have the properties/attributes `on<event-name>` for assigning some code which should be execute "on" the occurrence of the event. 2: Yes, a function is just like any other value (string, array, boolean). In `var foo = "bar";`, `foo` references a string. In `function foo(){}` or `var foo = function(){};`, `foo` references a function. `foo()` would call that function.

Comment: Thank you again for an informative answer. I think this was an educational post and I accepted your answer so would you upvote my question for me and also for the other users who need information on this issue? Also thanks for the article I will make sure to read it!

Answer (score 4):

It's because you wrote `changeColors()` instead of just `changeColors`.  The `()` tell JavaScript to call the function.

In other words, `changeColors` by itself is a reference to the function, while `changeColors()` refers to the function *and then calls it*.  The result of the function call (the return value from the function) is what's ultimately passed to `addEventListener()`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think we need to understand when to use the prefix "on" with the event type. In IE 8 or less then IE8 we use attachEvent and detachEvent which are equivalent to addEventListener and removeEventListener. There are some differences which are not required for this question.

While using attachEvent the event type is prefixed with "on" but in addEventListener no prefix is used.

hence,

```
    elem.attachEvent("onclick",listener); // <= IE8

    elem.addEventListener("click",listener,[,useCapture]); // other browsers
```

Answer (score -1):

I've needed to do something like that too. I have an infoWindow in my map and I need to handle a click event on paragraph in that infoWindow. So I did it like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() 
     {
        paragraph = document.getElementById("idOfThatParagraph");
        paragraph.addEventListener("click", function()
        {
          //actions that I need to do
        });
    });
```

It works for me. So I hope it will help someone :)